# Is it possible to compare 2 dimensions in a Google Analytics query filter?

Tags: api, filter, dimensions, google-analytics-api

I'm just starting out with the Google Analytics API and am wondering if it's possible to compare two dimensions via an operand in the filters I pass in the query.  And by wondering I mean I've tried it, but have had no success.

Specifically I'm trying to compare 2 custom variable values.  One holds the user who created a post (customVarValue3), the other the user who is viewing the post (customVarValue5). I want to get the pageviews only for the visitors who are not also the creator. The filter looks like this (without urlencoding applied):

```
ga:customVarValue3!=ga:customVarValue5
```

The full query (url encoded) looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga%3Axxxxxx&dimensions=ga%3AcustomVarValue1%2Cga%3AcustomVarValue2%2Cga%3AcustomVarValue3&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3AcustomVarValue3!%3Dga%3AcustomVarValue5&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&start-date=2012-02-09&end-date=2012-02-23&max-results=50
```

However, it returns the same results (and I know there are results where ga:customVarValue3 == ga:customVarValue5).

Probably it isn't possible, but I just wanted to see if anyone knew how to achieve this or has a workaround or something.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer to this question! Haven't solved it later?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible using the GAv3 API in its present state. You can, however, get all the results by using the specified two custom variables as the dimensions for a report, and programmatically filter out the unnecessary results.

Some simple construct like

```
for(var item in collatedResultsListwithDimensions) {
    for(var row in item.rows) {
        if(row[0]!=row[1])
            newResultRows.push(row);
    }
}
```

Now your `newResultRows` will have those rows where `row[1]!=row[0]` assuming the two custom variables you mentioned are the first two dimensions.

Comment: is it possible in v4 API?